# Centos 7 Cron job does not work

Tags: cron, daemon, startup, centos7, cron-task

1. I am using CentOS 7 and I want to run a cron job on one of the sudo user account
2. I have installed the package "cronie" which is required for cron Jobs on Centos7.
3. When I edited the file "**crontab -u username -e**" with "**@reboot /home/username/startup.sh**" expecting it to start after every reboot.
4. When I used the command "**crontab -u username -l**" and the result is "**@reboot /home/username/startup.sh**"
5. I have rebooted the system and I do not see the service running. Is there something that I am missing???.

Comment: have you found a solution?